# Cannot connect to OpenFire server remotely

Tags: azure, xmpp, openfire

I have the following setup

An Azure VM running windows that has OpenFire installed and configured.

I have turned the firewall off on this VM.

I have enabled the end points for the VM in the Azure Portal

I can telnet and PsPing to port 5222 remotely.

I can log in and connect to the server via spark locally

I cannot connect remotely at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was a follows.

Port 5222 uses TLS and and 5223 uses SSL. This is the usual setup. Somehow, these were reverse on my installation and this was causing the issue.

There are 3 ways to fix this ranked from more desirable to least:

- Reconfigure the OpenFire ports to use the correct technology.
- Set your XMPP client to use OldStyleSSL
- Configure your VM endpoints to swap the ports around.

As I said, the most desirable outcome here is to reconfigure the server so that others trying to connect to it will not have these issues.